# postgresql login from remote

Tags: windows, postgresql, port

I want to give remote access to my postresql db (8.2) to computers that are at the same lan, at the default config I have added this line to pg_hba.conf where xxx.xx.xx.xx is the ip of the machine that hosts postgresql. This machine is a windows 2k server.

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0         password
host    all         all         xxx.xx.xx.xx/24         password
```

There no firewall or such blocking the connection between and `listen_addresses = '*' for postgresql.conf .

Comment: Use Sysinternals' TCPView or Process Explorer to check if PgSQL is really listening for an incoming connection.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm guessing it isn't working?

Presumably it should be 
host    all         all         xxx.xx.xx.0/24         password
not
host    all         all         xxx.xx.xx.xx/24         password

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but neither works :(

Answer (score 0):

`pg_hba` applies the first rule to match, so your second line is never used.
Where is it blocking ? network or authentication ? If it's authentication, you may want to try the `md5` method (s/password/md5/).

Comment: giving me "not listening" from the remote machine, tried md5 but doesn't help

Comment: Then check all these settings http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/runtime-config-connection.html -> listen_addresses defaults to 'localhost'

Answer (score 0):

I've recently done this on Postgres 8.3.  I did it on a linux system, but the procedure sounds similar.

I followed the instructions [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html)

It looks like the only significant difference is instead of 'password' in the hba conf it is 'trust'.  Essentially I believe that means it allows the host to connect with any user versus password which takes a cleartext password.

That setting may rule out a password issue.

The next thing I'd suggest is to try adding a single IP address for a specific host and try connecting.  You could also try connecting locally, by specifying the server's ip address.

Answer (score 0):

Error messages should be logged in your application eventlog. You should look there to troubleshoot your configuration (and maybe append the errors from the logs to your question to give us the possibility to help you).